# Change of queryparam not detected

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm having a problem to sync my filter properly. I `subscribe` to the `queryParams` of `ActivatedRoute`. There I get the `query` and my three filter criteria.

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.route
      .queryParams
      .subscribe(queryParams => {
        this._query = queryParams['query'];
        this._heightFilter = queryParams['height'];
        this._colourFilter = queryParams['colour'];
        this._weightFilter = queryParams['weight'];
        // Do some request to WS to get the new data
      });
  }
```

When ever I click on a filter, lets say `colour:blue`, I call my `reloadPage()` and give the new `queryparams` and navigate to the same page just with the new `queryparams`.

```
  private reloadPage(): void {
    const queryParams: NavigationExtras = {};
    queryParams['query'] = this._query;
    //Bring filter arrays into shape for queryParams
    this.prepareFiltersForParams(queryParams);
    this.router.navigate([], {
      queryParams,
    });
```

This works all fine. Now we have selected `colour:blue`, but I also want `colour:orange`. I will be added to the `queryParams['colour']`, which then contains `blue` and `orange`. But for some reason `orange` is nether added to the url, even it exits in `queryParams['colour']`. If I add now a filter of another criteria, lets say `height`, everything works nice and smooth and the `height` filter will be added and also the `colour:orange`.

It seems to me that the `change detection` of the `this.route.queryParams.subscribe` is just not picking up the change of the `queryParams['colour']` and therefore just not updates.

I also opened a GH issue [angular#17609](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17609).

Comment: Can you make a plunker for this? You can have only one value in `color` but how did you add two values?

Comment: I can try to get it into plunker. In GH I have describe the issue a little deeper: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17609

Comment: _You can have only one value in color but how did you add two values_?

Comment: This is basically what I want to achieve: `www.awesome.org/search?query=AppleTree&colour=blue,orange` Have a look to [angular#17609](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17609)

Comment: Can you provide us with ALL the relevant code in the component (every method involved) and possibly even template code. After looking at the GH issue, it doesn't really add up

Answer (score 2):

See the angular documentation https://angular.io/guide/router#activatedroute-the-one-stop-shop-for-route-information.

You probably need to use the switchmap operator:

> Since the parameters are provided as an Observable, you use the switchMap operator to provide them for the id parameter by name and tell the HeroService to fetch the hero with that id.
>
> The switchMap operator allows you to perform an action with the current value of the Observable, and map it to a new Observable. As with many rxjs operators, switchMap handles an Observable as well as a Promise to retrieve the value they emit.
>
> The switchMap operator will also cancel any in-flight requests if the user re-navigates to the route while still retrieving a hero.

From the tour of heroes (https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5#revise-the-herodetailcomponent):

> The switchMap operator maps the id in the Observable route parameters to a new Observable, the result of the HeroService.getHero() method.
>
> If a user re-navigates to this component while a getHero request is still processing, switchMap cancels the old request and then calls HeroService.getHero() again.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using your reloadPage() void just use [routerLink] attribute like so :

```html
<a *ngFor="let product of products"
  [routerLink]="['/product-details', product.id]">
  {{ product.name }}
</a>
```

https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/routeparams.html

This article might be useful for you